# php not running javascript more than once

Tags: javascript, php

When this code is loaded in the webpage it will detect that $Update is equal to 1 and run the below code. but after setting $Update back to 0 and then back to 1 it will not re-run the code below.

i am refreshing a DIV that contains all of the php code every 5 seconds using javascript but it still will not run more than once on the initial load.

any ideas?

thanks in advance

```
if($Update == "1"){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("Sub1").style.display="none"</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("Sub1Move").style.display="block"</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">$( "#Sub1Move" ).animate({marginTop: "-=34px",}, 2000, function() {});</script>';
    sleep(8);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("Sub1").style.display="block"</script>';
    $Update = "0";

}
```

Comment: That is not how this works. PHP is a server-side language and Javascript is client-side. If you need PHP to run multiple times, look at making an AJAX call to your server. See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 1):

PHP happens on the server side, and Javascript only affects stuff on the client side. You can't refresh only a specific `<div>` with Javascript hoping it will trigger the PHP code that generated that specific `<div>`. In general everything you wish to let happen 'live' you should write in Javascript, mixing PHP and Javascript like you're trying to do now is somewhat possible, but not advisable and a lot harder.

So what you would wish to do is

```
<script>
    // [...]
    $( "#Sub1Move" ).animate({marginTop: "-=34px",}, 2000, function() {});

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("Sub1").style.display="block"
    }, 8000);
</script>
```

Comment: See i have tried putting my script on its own and calling it from the php but that did not seem to work. ill try it again but i dont think it will work.

Comment: You can't call Javascript from PHP, PHP finishes when you load the page, everything after that is Javascript. There is no mixing the two (well, there is: through AJAX or slow loading iframes, but that's irrelevant now).

Comment: so if i wanted to run some javascript to move a div tag every time a variable in my php code changed, how would i do this?

Comment: You can still run some javascript or Jquery with some PHP, Although it is considered a bad practise !

Comment: @JoeCory Simply put: You can't. If something in your database is changing or some other external source you will need to use AJAX to poll a php file which you change accordingly each time.

Answer (score -1):

your php code must have for loop but its not good to call js from php to do a job that can be done with js alone.

```
this is better:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func1() {
        //your code
    }
    setInterval(func1, 5000);
</script>
```